# Multiple Cross Domain AJAX calls. Why does IE<9 forget session?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer, safari

I have pages with 4 AJAX requests that fire in order to send an order request through to a 3rd party system. Firstly, the product information is sent, then the customer details to attach to the order, then any notes applicable to the order and finally a 4th request to "complete" the order.

Everything works fine in IE9, Firefox (mac + pc), Safari (mac + pc) and Chrome (mac + pc), however, when the requests are sent from IE<9, the AJAX requests are fired correctly and correct responses are returned without error, but it appears that it is sending through a different session for each of the calls so the 3rd party system recognises the 4 different requests as coming from different sessions.

If I send the requests one by one through the address bar in IE8, everything works as expected and the order is tied together, it is only when sending via jQuery .ajax that the session is forgotten.

Is there anything I can do to force these browsers to maintain the session?

Here is my code:

```
//function to add the product to the cart and cascade down to finalise the order
function addToCart(){
    var jsonurl = "xxxxx/additem?variationID="+$('input[name="variationID"]').val()+"&token="+APIKey+"&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
        url:jsonurl,
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            if (data.response == "success"){
                addLeadCustomer();
            } else {
                displayEnquiryError();
            }


        },
        error:function(data){
            displayEnquiryError();
        }
    })  
}


//function to add the lead customer and cascade down to finalise the order
function addLeadCustomer(){
    //add the lead customer to the order in J6
    jsonurl = "http://xxxxx/leadcustomer?token="+APIKey+"&details[FirstName]="+$('input[name="Name"]').val()+"&details[Email]="+$('input[name="Email"]').val()+"&details[HomePhone]="+$('input[name="Phone"]').val()+"&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
        url:jsonurl,
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            if (data.response.ID > 0){
                updateOrderAdditionalInfo();
            }else{
                displayEnquiryError();
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            displayEnquiryError();
        }
    })
}

//function to update the order with the additional info and cascade down to finalise the order
function updateOrderAdditionalInfo(){
    //update the order with additional information
    jsonurl = "http://xxxxx/updateorder?token="+APIKey+"&details[Notes]="+$('input[name="EnquiryDate"]').val()+"\n\n"+$('select[name="NumberNights"]').val()+" nights\n\n"+$('select[name="NumberPeople"]').val()+" people\n\n"+$('textarea[name="Comments"]').val()+"&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
        url:jsonurl,
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            if (data.response == "success"){
                completeOrder();

            }else{
                displayEnquiryError();
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            displayEnquiryError();
        }
    });
}

//function to complete the order
function completeOrder(){
    //complete the "order"
    jsonurl = "http://xxxxx/completeorder?token="+APIKey+"&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
        url:jsonurl,
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            if (data.response == "success"){
                $('.waiting').fadeOut(function(){
                    $('.enquirySuccess').fadeIn();
                    $('.cartItemsHolder').empty();
                    $('.cartItemsHolder').html('We have received your itinerary');
                })
            }
        },
        error:function(data){
            displayEnquiryError();  
        }
    });
}

$('#Form_enquiryForm').submit(function(){
    validateForm();
    if (failedValidation == 0){
        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
            $('.waiting').fadeIn();
            //add the package to the cart
            addToCart();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

UPDATE: I came across posts which lead to the impression that it could be because of IE8's cacheing. This lead me to try cache:false in my AJAX call and also adding a random number parameter to the querystring (&cachebuster="+Math.random()) but neither solved the issue.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, it is acceptable to post an answer for your own question and accept it. I'd move your update #2 to an answer so that you can "close" this question out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that it is because of IE8's default handling of 3rd party cookies. It blocks them. By turning my security settings right down in IE8 I was able to get the desired behaviour. It looks like we are going to have to re-write the API's to pass back an identifier that we can fire off each time to tie the requests together.

Update: Safari also rejects 3rd party cookies by default. I had fired the API from the address bar in Safari prior to testing which had set the cookie. After I reset Safari and retested, it exhibited the same behaviour as IE8.

Update2: We actually went about solving this in a different way. We set up an API to just set a session and close the window. Then, with jQuery, we detect the browser. If it is IE<=8 or Safari we launch a popup to the new API (this sets the session and immediately closes the window). We can now use our session with our application. We also set a cookie with jQuery with the same expiry time as the session from the cart to let us know that we've already set the session.

It's not perfect by any means.. for instance if the jQuery cookie is lost then we have to start as a new session on the cart. If the Cart session is lost, then we will keep unknowingly firing away at the cart without it remembering us which brings us back to the initial problem.... and don't get me started on pop up blockers :) It is however a quick fix until we implement something more robust.